# How to read from an encrypted OBB file using Google's APK Expansion Zip Library?

Tags: android, encryption, apk-expansion-files

I understand how to read a plain OBB file. However, there doesn't seem to be any APIs in the library to pass in a key for cases in which the file is encrypted.

Does the APK Expansion Zip Library simply not support the opening of encrypted OBB files? If so, do I have no choice but to use the [StorageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageManager.html)?

Comment: Seems no one who has a solution for this :(

Comment: @anhnt Nope. The developers of the library completely forgot about encryption. I ended up using the StorageManager. It's almost as easy to use anyway.

Comment: How did you resolve this issue? Can we read obb file with encrypted key? Currently I'm mounting obb file without key

Comment: @anhnt I just used [storage manager's mount method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageManager.html).

Comment: did you create obb file with JOBB tool? I didnt have a chance to make storage manager work

Comment: Yes. I used the JOBB tool.